# Parameterized Remote Trigger plugin doesn't respect Build Token Root

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to trigger a job from one Jenkins (A) on another one (B). I've installed 2 plugins:

1. Parameterized Remote Trigger
2. Build Token Root

My issue is, that I'm able to trigger build on Jenkins (B) using for example curl and token only, which means the Build Token Root plugin is working as expected, but Parameterized Remote Trigger seems to don't respect this.

I probably should mention that I've tried different auth options, Trust All certs, etc.

[My Jenkins (A) config:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQbse.png)

Logs are the same with and without Build Token Root support enabled.

[Logs I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft6cG.png):

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by allowing Anonymous users Overall Read and Job Read access. It appears this is necessary because the Parameterized Remote Trigger plugin attempts to call additional APIs apart from just the `/build` and `/buildWithParameters` and those calls are the ones that fail.

It makes sense that, in order to have the default blocking capability, you need to call additional APIs to poll, but even setting `blockBuildUntilComplete : false` did not fix the issue. Considering that Parameterized Remote Trigger plugin plainly says it "plays well" with the Build Token plugin in its documentation, it really is not an easy feat to make them work together.

In my opinion, using the two together isn't an ideal solution because of the necessity for allowing unauthenticated users to browse your jenkins instance via the ui - I suspect you could (although I haven't tried it) get an API Token for a user with only Overall Read and Job Read access instead of giving all Anonymous Users the rights, but this includes the overhead of managing a user and an API Token, which defeats our primary motivation to use the Build Token plugin in the first place.

Comment: Hi, your answer is good, but since it contains a lot of text, it could benefit from a little organization. Perhaps some headers (# or ## in MD) to separate different sections of your answer (main answer vs additional thoughts). I also like using horizontal lines ( ===== in MD I think )